# ¿Cómo puedo sacar de mi lista de arreglo, cierto números?

Tags: php, array, bucle-for, bucles, while

actualmente estoy comenzando en el mundo de la programación, en especial en php, y tengo un ejercicio por realizar. Añado imagen con la descripción de mi código.

[image: Ejercicio con blucles while y for]

y este es el codigo que hice, agradeceria mucho la segurencias de la falla o que me falta para realizar lo que me pide.

```
<?php

$numeros = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
  $i=4;

while($i < count($numeros) ){
  echo $numeros[$i]. " ";
  $i++;

];

>?
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y cual es el problema?ç

Answer (score 0):

FOR

```
<?php
$numeros = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
$numeroInicial = 4;
$numeroFinal = 8;

for($i = $numeroInicial; $i <= $numeroFinal; $i++){
    echo $numeros[$i].' ';
}
?>
```

WHILE

```
<?php

$numeros = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
$numeroInicial = 4;
$numeroFinal = 8;

while($numeroInicial <= $numeroFinal){
  echo $numeros[$numeroInicial].' ';
  $numeroInicial++;
}
?>
```

Eso sería lo más basico. Estaría bien también comprobar que el número final no sea mayor que la longitud del array para evitar errores, etc.

Comment: Si, se que es lo mas básico, pero ando comenzando en el mundo de la programación y a veces me revuelvo un poco. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: No me referia a lo más basico como lo más facil. Sino al ejemplo en si, que es lo basico del ejercicio, que habria que añadir comprobaciones de que los numeros esten dentro del tamaño "valido" del array etc. Espero que no te lo hayas tomado  a mal. Un saludo

Comment: No al contrario muchisimas gracias. Una pregunta mas, porque  al imprimir la variable en el for, le quitaste los signos de incremento al contador $i?

Comment: Si te fijas, el for tiene un "i++" al final del parentesis . Es ahí donde se indica el incremento de la variable que utilizas como iterador.

Comment: Muchas gracias nuevamente. Te agradezco tu apoyo.